# Bootstrap-select in Bootstrap modal

Tags: bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I am using a Bootstrap-select dropdown in a modal, and I would like the modal to resize so the dropdown is fully visible when expanded.
Is there a way?

This is my code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/1.17/jquery.multiselect.filter.css"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/b75cc9b39e.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2bc6529db2.js"></script>





    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#exampleModal">Launch demo modal</button>


    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal"
        tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div
            class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-scrollable  modal-dialog-centered"
            role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body" style="overflow: hidden">


                    <form class="form-horizontal registerForm" method="post"
                        id="productForm">


                        <div class="container-fluid">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class='col-sm-3 text-right' style='height: 40px'>
                                    <span class="align-bottom"
                                        style="line-height: 40px; vertical-align: middle"><b>Field</b></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select dropdown w-100">
                                        <select class="selectpicker" id="Field" name="Field"
                                            data-width="100%">
                                            <option value="">Select a Field</option>
                                            <option data-icon="fas fa-font" value='1'>1</option>
                                            <option data-icon="fas fa-font" value='2'>2</option>
                                            <option data-icon="fas fa-font" value='3'>3</option>
                                            <option data-icon="fas fa-font" value='4'>4</option>
                                            <option data-icon="fas fa-font" value='5'>5</option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary pull-right" onclick="CloseModal()">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" name="send" value="Send" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As said, when I expand the dropdown the dimension of the modal does not change and the dropdown changes position, instead I would like the modal to change dimension and the dropdown not to change position.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the `.col-*` classes in this block

```
<div class='col-sm-3 text-right' style='height: 40px'>
    <span class="align-bottom" style="line-height: 40px; vertical-align: middle"><b>Field</b></span>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-7">
    <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select dropdown w-100">
        <select class="selectpicker" id="Field" name="Field" data-width="100%">
            <option value="">Select a Field</option>
            <option data-icon="fas fa-font" value='1'>1</option>
            <option data-icon="fas fa-font" value='2'>2</option>
            <option data-icon="fas fa-font" value='3'>3</option>
            <option data-icon="fas fa-font" value='4'>4</option>
            <option data-icon="fas fa-font" value='5'>5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can set

```
<div class='col-auto text-right' style='height: 40px'>
    ........
</div>
```

> with `col-auto` the element will take only the space that is needed.

And

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select dropdown w-100">
     ...........
    </div>
</div>
```

> with `col` the element will take the remaining space.

Regarding to the modal resize, the dropdown is not shown because it has absolute positioning.

If you know the number of items you can set a min-height to the modal content like this:

```
.modal-content {
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

If you want to expand the whole modal when the dropdown opens you should change the position of the dropdown menu like this:

```
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative!important;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Antonis, my problem though it that when I expand the dropdown the modal does not resize and shows only a part of the items of the dropdown.